# I'm trying to put as much constraint on user input as possible. I can't figure out how to limit input to 2 digits for '-DAY-' and '-MONTH-'

Tags: python, layout, constraints, user-input, pysimplegui

Here's my layout element

```
[sg.Text('DOB: dd/mm/yyyy     '),sg.InputText(key='-DAY-', size=(2,1)),sg.Text('/'),sg.InputText(key='-MONTH-',size=(2,1)),sg.Text('/'),sg.InputText(key='-YEAR-',size=(4,1))],
```

The size parameter limits the box size but the user can still type as long a number as they like you just can't see all of it in the window

Answer (score 0):

Validation by tkinter code here

```py
from datetime import datetime
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def validate(text, width, limit):
    w = len(text)
    if text:
        return False if (
            (w > width)          or
            (not text.isdigit()) or
            (int(text) > limit)  or
            (int(text) < 1)
        ) else True
    else:
        return True

now = datetime.now()
items = [('Year', now.year), ('Month', now.month), ('Day', now.day)]

font = ("Courier New", 16, 'bold')
sg.set_options(font=font)

layout = [[sg.Text(item, size=5), sg.Input(date, size=4, justification='center', key=item)] for item, date in items]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, use_default_focus=False, finalize=True)
vcmd_year   = (window.TKroot.register(lambda text, width=4, limit=9999:validate(text, width, limit)), '%P')
vcmd_month  = (window.TKroot.register(lambda text, width=2, limit=  12:validate(text, width, limit)), '%P')
vcmd_day    = (window.TKroot.register(lambda text, width=2, limit=  31:validate(text, width, limit)), '%P')
window['Year' ].widget.configure(validate='all', validatecommand=vcmd_year )
window['Month'].widget.configure(validate='all', validatecommand=vcmd_month)
window['Day'  ].widget.configure(validate='all', validatecommand=vcmd_day  )

for key in ('Year', 'Month', 'Day'):
    window[key].bind("<FocusIn>", " FocusIn")

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event.endswith("FocusIn"):
        key = event.split(" ")[0]
        window[key].update(select=True)

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for that Jason, a very thorough answer. I'm just going to run it a few times in the debugger to get my head around it and then hopefully incorporate it into my application. Cheers, Ian